# Метку "локализация" сделать вторичной по отношению к метке "перевод"

Tags: предложение, локализация, метки

При создании вопросов, касающихся переводов, разумнее было использовать именно метку [перевод](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4), как основную, а не второстепенную, как сейчас. Даже при поиске меток на странице [меток](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags) по слову "перевод" выдаются какие-то крохи:

> [image: перевод-метки]

И многим даже невдомек о том, что есть другая метка, с более замудрённым названием, которая занимается вопросами перевода. Зачем усложнять повседневную работу?

## Дополнение

Тут вот указывают на то, что "перевод" более узкое понятие, чем "локализация", но, слушайте, таким же образом "локализация" более узкое понятие по отношению к "изменение". Ежели львиная доля вопросов под меткой "локализация" касается непосредственно переводов, то, быть может, не так уж она и важна, как нам её хотят представить и не лучше бы её сделать побочной в таком случае?

Comment: Перевод - более узкое понятие

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F настолько узкое, что почти в каждом вопросе, на первой странице, речь идёт именно о нём.

Comment: Локализовывать можно и интерфейс (например на арабский, китайский), а перевод касается конкретно текста, это действительно более узкое понятие.

Comment: "Зачем усложнять повседневную работу?" Кстати, а вот это вообще о чём?

Comment: Для каждого такого вопроса, я ищу первым делом метку "перевод", которой нет.

Comment: @edem метка [meta-tag:перевод] есть. Это синоним метки [meta-tag:локализация]. На поиск это не влияет.

Answer (score 4):

Заменять более широкий термин более узким, наверное, всё же не стоит. А вот чтобы "крохи" при поиске не казались крохами можно было бы выводить описание для дублирующих меток сразу под ними, а не оставлять пустое место. При этом, если навести курсор (правда, сейчас всё больше становится устройств с тачскринами и без курсоров как таковых) на дублирующую метку можно увидеть подробное описание из основной:

> [image: подсказка]

В этом случае обозначенная проблема уже не выглядит такой бескомпромиссной.

Comment: Можно разделить вопросы перевода и остальные исправления, связанный с подгоном внешнего вида под русскоязычное отображение.

Comment: @edem какую цель преследует такое разделение? Для вопросов по внешнему виду вполне уместно добавлять метку [meta-tag:дизайн] к метке [meta-tag:локализация]. Но если я вас правильно понимаю, вы хотите просто убрать метку [локализация] с вопросов, посвященных переводу интерфейса сайта, и заменить её какой-то другой, например, упомянутой ранее [перевод]. Я пока не вижу в этом какой-то пользы для сообщества, если честно.

Comment: Если среди опавшей листвы 87 листьев жёлтого цвета, а 13 зелёного, то называть опавшие листья зелёными, ну такое. При таком разделение будет точно понятно, что речь идёт о переводе, а не о, к примеру, внешнем виде дат, принятых в разных странах. Ну и к тому же, при создании таких вопросов, будет проще добавлять эту метку "перевод", а не как сейчас, вчитываться в пояснение к метке "локализация".

Comment: @edem добавлять метку [перевод] при создании вопросов никто не мешает, она просто автоматически заменится на [локализация]. Если кто-то планирует заниматься адаптацией сайта на русский язык, то такому человеку стоит обращать внимание на все возможные аспекты этой адаптации, с датами и жёлтыми опавшими листьями. А также различными ограничениями дизайна, когда надо бы использовать длинное слово, но вот движок сайта недостаточно гибок для этого. Поэтому сухой [перевод] тут всё равно не будет достаточно подходящей меткой. Может быть вам будет полезно обратить внимание на метку [meta-tag:термины].

Comment: Вот, даже "термины" и то, не подразумевают слово "перевод", которое первое приходит на ум для таких вопросов.

Comment: @edem, _"Если среди опавшей листвы 87 листьев жёлтого цвета, а 13 зелёного",_ то называть их надо _опавшими_ [локализация], а не _жёлтыми_ [перевод].

Comment: @Qwertiy Так уже сказано же в третьем слове, что листва *опавшая* и внимание смещено на цветовую окраску. Зачем городить масло масляное?) Кстати, для вас не будет откровением узнать, что под "локализацией" также подразумевают обнаружение?

Comment: @edem, а под переводом ещё понимают бесполезный расход ресурсов. А сайт-то тут при чём?

Comment: @Qwertiy это вы про стареньких бабушек, которым помогают добраться на другую сторону дороги?! Мда уж. Не ожидал такого...

Comment: @edem, эм, нет. Я про что-то в духе "он пытался приготовить обед, но только продукты перевёл".

Comment: @Qwertiy фух, так то ладно, успокоили.